# Analyze Google Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I am looking to connect online leads data in Salesforce with Google Adwords keywords. Is there any way to have following fields I can add in Lead.

- Click Cost
- Keyword

Comment: I learned so far that there is no way to retrieve Click cost via Adwords but via Manual Tagging we can get Keyword, Campaign details.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the lead field "lead_source" on salesforce and set that it takes the query string parameter into that field.

If you use PHP It will like the following

```
<input type="hidden" id="lead_source" name="lead_source" value="<?php $_GET['url_source'] ?>"/>
```

Now, when you set the target URL on Adwords in you should employ the **keyword replacement**, using the same query string name.

```
http://www.example.com?url_source={keyword}
```

or put after url_source here whatever extra data you want (I put more than just the keyword). But I don't know of a reason to get the cost there, only the keyword.

The problem with this approach is that you can only take the keyword from URL if the user downloaded on the same landing page (if he navigates to another page, you lose the query string parameter). If you want to keep this information for a later conversion, you will have to store this data in a cookie. Try this project if you want to implement it: 
https://github.com/dm-guy/utm-alternative